# How to position label text with css

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a simple login form and I want position these two label texts on top their respective inputs instead of having this big space gap. Fairly new sorry.

HTML

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <label>Username
        <input type="username" class="button-user">
    </label>
    <label>Password
        <input type="password" class="button-pw">
    </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="button-space">
    <input type="submit" class="button">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
fieldset {
width: 200px;
}
.button-space {
height: 50px;
background: #f0f0f2;
border-top: 1px;
}
.button {
margin-top: 13px;
}
.button-pw {
margin-top: 20px;
}
.button-user {
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypNUU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should solve it ;)

```
fieldset {
    width: 200px;
}
.button-space {
    height: 50px;
    background: #f0f0f2;
    border-top: 1px;
}
.button {
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.button-pw {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.button-user {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypNUU/5/

And if you don't want that gap space between the PW-textbox and then button, then set `margin-bottom` to 0px in `.button-pw`
http://jsfiddle.net/ypNUU/6/

Comment: Thank you very much! And for everyone else's answers!

Answer (score 2):

Remove these rules:

```
.button-pw {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.button-user {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

They are adding the gap between the labels and the fields.  [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wa6a8/).

Comment: `xmargin` ? can you explain

Comment: seeing your reputation I thought this is something new in css :P :P

Comment: I did that intentionally because I wanted to move the text-box a bit down. Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change the margin-to like this

```
.button-pw {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.button-user {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes...

```
/*.button-pw {
    margin-top: 20px;
}*/
.button-user {
    /*margin-top: 20px;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And it will look like...

[image: login form screenshot]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ypNUU/4/